# What do you think is the best option for Previous/Next icon buttons alongside product carousel in mobile?

Tags: mobile, buttons, carousel

I have the following ideas of how to solve this problem:

[image: mockups]

What do you think is the best option to present a product image carousel alongside previous/next buttons for nearby category products?

Comment: It sounds like you're either asking us to design a system for you (which is not what we're here for) or you're asking us to link to lots of examples of this design pattern (which isn't what we're here for either). We can help you solve a specific problem, but we can't do all your work for you.

Comment: Pardon me. I thought there were 2 or 3 common design patterns outlines that you could share. I'm not a graphic designer or UX specialist. Just a store owner trying to port my ecommerce site for a mobile experience.

Comment: That's not really what this site is about though. It's a Q&A site, not a forum, so we're here to give you 'The' answer that *solves* your problem. Not just give examples of something. However if you can explain your specific situation then we can probably tell you the most appropriate way to display it.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to draw my idea. The thing is that I don't see that Previous/Next buttons to navigate to other product views are very common in mobile, apart from the search results or category view...

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I learned how to draw IU mockups.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding right, you're asking whether previous/next buttons should be placed next to the thing they go to the previous/next of or whether they should be next to the category they browse through. Is that correct?

Comment: What I was asking is how to compliment two different "depths of navigation": navigate through images from the product itself and navigate through closeby products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be either Option 1 or Option 2.

Which one depends on what it is that the user sees when tapping on 'previous' or 'next'. If they see another product, then it's Option 1. If the see another category, then it's Option 2. Anything else would create confusion for the user.

Comment: I can see what you mean. Yes, Option 1 is the most suitable for my use case. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is it an app or responsive website?

App:

Why have Next / Previous icons to select products. The indicators below inform the user there is more to view and to swipe left or right to view the next product while still remaining in the catergory. The area you are using to place the icons would be better used for navigating the app.

If the icons go anywhere it should be on the image itself to prompt the swipe.

Responsive Website: Why have Next / Previous at all? Scroll. Keep it simple.

Comment: The idea is to easily navigate through the other products of a category or through the search results because I've been told that it's annoying to have to go back everytime to see the next product's details.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of examples online showing how to display products, interact and navigate.

www.rudys.paris is a good example. The navigation is simple. The indicators inform the user there is more to see before making the decision to purchase. No more than four clicks in from the home page and three from the catergory. The more simple the design the more simple the experience and the easier it will be for the user to make a purchase. Do not complicate the proccess. When money is involved you want the user to feel in control, informed and confident.